# How do I deserialize objects in Io?

Tags: serialization, iolanguage

I've found the *serialized* and *justSerialized* methods on Object and already successfully serialized objects to files, but I cannot find a matching *deserialize* method.

Is there none or am I just too stupid to find it?

Comment: never heard of iolanguage so far. this looks interesting

Comment: Take a look at the file. I think the serialization process generates code to re-create the object. You just need to read and ``eval`` the result. Not sure, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [`doString`](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Object/doString) or [`doMessage`](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Object/doMessage) should do what you need (though I can't confirm this at moment because I don't have Io running on this machine).

For eg:

```
doString( yourSerializedString )
```

or

```
doMessage( yourSerializedString asMessage )
```

**Update** - Can now confirm that `doString` or `doMessage` does work. Full example below:

#### Foo.io

```
Foo := Object clone do (
    name ::= nil
)
```

#### serialize.io

```
doRelativeFile("Foo.io")

baz := Foo clone setName("baz")

// serialize "baz" object to file
File with("serialized.data") open write(baz serialized) close
```

#### restore_object.io

```
doRelativeFile("Foo.io")

baz := doString(
    File with("serialized.data") open readLines join
)
```

In fact you can also *deserialize* the object with [`doRelativeFile`](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Object/doRelativeFile) or [`doFile`](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Object/doFile):

```
baz := doRelativeFile("serialized.data")
```

Because serialized data is just Io code.

/I3az/